# Playing sounds frequently - even when display is off

Tags: javascript

I'm currently building a PWA, which has the following feature:

A mp3 is played every minute (setTimeout) for as long as the user defined it. And it works fine.
However, the sound stops, when the display is off.

These are my questions:
- Is there a possibility to play the sound although the display is off?
- Is there a possibility to prevent, that the display is turned off?

I'm in need of a systemic overview about my possibilities. If you have an possible solution, I will add them to the summary :)

Comment: Display has nothing to do with sound. Could it be a `sleep` problem? Workstations are usually configured to suspend the system after a certain amount of idle time.

Comment: is it a mobile decide or desktop, I'll assume Desktop: turning off the display does only stop the sound if your sound comes from the display itself, or the windows power mode says that not only the display but the whole system will switch to an idle setting... and you can't control those settings through a website...

Comment: Since you stated that you are building a Progressive Web App and turning off the display results in no sound I strongly assume you are facing this problem on a smartphone. The bad news: You very likely can not do anything about this. Mobile OSes will put most (background) tasks to sleep when locked or screen is off to save the users battery. This is especially true for browser applications.